# Cribbage and scoring 31 plus go

Tags: cribbage

Recognizing that I am arguing against pretty clear rules, but my buddy and I got in an argument regarding the logic behind only getting two pegs/points (Vs. 3) when you get a "go" from your partner and then place one or more cards down to eventually get to 31.

My logic (working against the rules) is that I should get 1 peg/point for my partners "go" and 2 pegs/points for reaching 31 (total of 3 points for the flurry of activity).  My argument is based on the fact that at any other time during the game when my partner says "go" I get 1 point......the only exception to this is when I place my cards down after the go and they result in a 31.  I argued with him last night that if the inventor of cribbage was alive today and I pointed out that I should get 3 points (1 for the go and 2 for hitting 31 directly) that they would say "hmmm....you are right....I missed that".

His rationale, is that when scoring 31, you are getting one point for hitting 31 exactly and 1 bonus point representing your partners' inability to play an additional card (his "go").  Hey says "whether a "go" is said or not, the go is implied when you place the last card at the end of the round to make 31....thus giving you two points when you reach 31 even when a "go" is communicated".

Any insight into how to argue either side of this scoring mess?

Comment: Your buddy is right.

Answer (score 14):

The [official cribbage rules](http://www.cribbage.org/rules/) make this incredibly clear:

> [Rule 1.6 - Definitions](http://www.cribbage.org/rules/rule1.asp#section6)
>   ... 
>   go: Called by a player who cannot play a card without exceeding the cumulative count of 31; the opponent scores one point, or two if reaching exactly 31.

In this, calling a 31 is just a special case of a go.

Answer (score 2):

31 played with the last card scores two points. This is because there is no score for "last card" - it's just that the last card is *always* a "go"; just because people say "one for last card" doesn't mean that that's why they're getting a point - they're really getting a point for the final "go".

Also note that the "go" isn't scored until all possible cards have been placed. If player A calls 25, and player B says "go", player A doesn't score until they have placed any further cards not passing 31. Once all such cards, if any, have been played, player A scores 2 points if they reached 31 (essentially go=1 + bonus for 31=1), otherwise one point is scored for the "normal" go.

Of course pairs or sequences may also be scored while finishing the journey to 31, and those are officially scored before the "go".

Answer (score -3):

I used to agree with your buddy, but now I agree with you.  I play an online game of cribbage.  The game gives me one point when my partner says ‘go’ and two more points if I get 31 exactly after the go.

Answer (score -4):

When you have a pair which will put you @31 IE 2 pairs of 2 that is 2 points for the pair and two points for the 31 obtained. A total of four points.